# extracing elements with highest & second highest occurrence in python

Tags: python

I am having a collection of strings in python in sorted (descending) order. i.e.

```
({'word1':4, 'word2':3 ,'word3':3  'word4':2 'word5':1 ...})
```

I need to extract all the words with highest & second highest orders of occurrences.
Here is my code snippet:

```
actualKeyWords = heapq.nlargest(2, Counter(possibleKeyWords), key=lambda x:x[1]).
```

I am new to python pls help

Comment: No need to use `heapq`; `Counter(possibleKeyWords).most_common(2)` will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because looping over the `Counter()` object only returns *keys*, not tuples of `(keyword, count)` values.

There is no need to use `heapq` explicitly here, the `Counter()` object will do that *for* you when you call the [`Counter.most_common()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
actualKeywords = Counter(possibleKeywords).most_common(2)
```

This gives you a list with two `(keyword, count)` tuples. If you want *just* the keywords, use:

```
actualKeywords = [k for (k, c) in Counter(possibleKeywords).most_common(2)]
```